# Zabbix Saml authentication with AWS Cognito Yesterday, 16:48

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, zabbix

I'm trying to configure SAML AWS Cognito authentication with my Zabbix 6.0.20

I copied from Federated identity provider sign-in the certificate and saved on zabbix server in: `/etc/ldap/ssl/idp.crt`
I updated the `/usr/share/zabbix/conf/zabbix.conf.php` file as below:

```
$SSO['SP_KEY'] = '/etc/ldap/ssl/key.pem';
$SSO['SP_CERT'] = '/etc/ldap/ssl/cert.pem';
$SSO['IDP_CERT'] = '/etc/ldap/ssl/idp.crt';
$SSO['SETTINGS'] = [];​
```

In Zabbix GUII Enabled SAML authentication​ with these parameters:

```
IdP entity ID: <User pool ID​>
SSO service URL: https://<cognito>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code&sco pe=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin+email+openid+phon e+profile&redirect_uri=https://<my_zabbix_domain>/index_sso.php?acs
SLO service URL:
Username attribute: userEmail
SP entity ID: <SAML_GROUP_NAME>
SP name ID format:
Sign
Messages <SELECTED>
Assertions <SELECTED>
AuthN requests <SELECTED>
Logout requests <SELECTED>
Logout responses <SELECTED>
Encrypt
Name ID <SELECTED>
Assertions <SELECTED>
Case-sensitive login <SELECTED>
```

When I try to login, I click on Sign in with Single Sign-On (SAML) and I redirect correctly to the Cognito authentication.
But after login I recieve the error:

> No permissions for system access. SAML Response not found, Only
> supported HTTP_POST Binding​

Could someone can help me to fix it, please?